# Generic Downcasting vs Non-generic downcasting

Tags: java, generics

T is Integer on runtime then how downcasting is being allowed here which isnt allowed in a non-generic class

```
//Allowed here 

class Generic<T>{
        Generic() {
        T[] array = (T[])new Object[5];     
} 
}

//Not Allowed here

class NonGeneric{
NonGeneric() {
        Integer[] array = (Integer[])new Object[5];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Type erasure is a bit weird.

`new Object[5]` always creates a new `Object[]`, never an `Integer[]`. If you cast an `Object[]` to an `Integer[]`, you get a `ClassCastException`.

A generic of type `T` is converted to `Object` at runtime but when using it, the returned `T` values are converted to the actual types (e. g. `Integer`).

The generic type `T[]` is actually `Object[]` at runtime and it will throw an exception when casting to the actual type (e. g. if `T` is `Integer`, casting the `T[]` to `Integer[]` will fail. Even the following will fail:

```java
<T> T[] test() {
    return (T[])new Object[5];
} 

//where using it
Integer[] arr = test();
```

As `T[]` is `Object[]` at runtime, `(T[])new Object[5]` will work. However, after it is returned, it (still `Object[]` is implicitly casted to `Integer[]` and that fails with a `ClassCastException`.

At runtime, the aforementioned code would look like this:

```java
Object[] test() {
    return (Object[])new Object[5];
} 

//where using it
Integer[] arr = (Integer[]) test();
```